# How can I change country in Amazon WebApp?

Tags: amazon

Amazon webapp launches the US site. How can I change it to the UK version of the website?

Comment: @EliahKagan I assume it's because Ubuntu installs the Amazon "web app" by default and the whole point of such things is to blur the differences between the desktop and the web.

Comment: @andrewsomething That's a good point. We should probably keep this open. (Close vote retracted.)

Comment: Did you find how to change foxy?

Answer (score 1):

First log in to your account. Under "your account" tab, select the "manage your content and devices" option. Then select "settings" tab and change the country settings.